# Blazor validation borders styling

Tags: css, validation, blazor

I am working on blazor validation, and I made the input forms with bootstrap classes which make them look round.

However Blazor's validation borders look Squared, and i would like to add some round shape to them.

Is there a way to access their style?

```
I can style bootstrap's border with these classes
.form-control.invalid {
    border-color: #dc3545;
}
.form-control.valid {
    border-color: #28a745;
}
```

But then there are two borders, one squared other round(bootstrap's)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `border-radius`

```
.form-control.invalid {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #dc3545;
}
.form-control.valid {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #28a745;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it styles the bootstrap border, and then it has still two borders, the square being the Blazor